# Haskell 128bit showing

Tags: haskell, 128-bit

My Question is that: Is it possible to show (2^63::Int) in 128 bit in Haskell?

Because of Int abs (2^63::Int) will not work because of the Int, but What If I have a 128 bit computer or compiler is it possible then to show the result?

Of course if it is possible, then please show me the way :)

Comment: I need with Int if it is possible on a 128 bit comp. or somehow...  Of course with Integer it works, but my question was not about that

Comment: you have a 128bit computer? ... and a Haskell compiler for this?

Comment: Searching for "Haskell int 128bit" immediately leads to [`Data.FixedPoint`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/FixedPoint-simple-0.6.1/docs/Data-FixedPoint.html) which provides an `Int128` data type (and even bigger types). There's also the [`Data.DoubleWord`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-dword-0.3/docs/Data-DoubleWord.html) package.  AFAIK the only guarantee for `Int` is that it has at least *29* bits. On 64bit machines it *may* allow for bigger values, but it's not guaranteed.

Comment: It's utterly irrelevant what architecture you have. You can easily show 2⁶³ (or 2¹⁰⁰⁰, for that matter), on a 16-bit machine. Of course it won't use machine-sized number types, but why would that matter? Sure, machine-words give the fastest performance, but if you're _showing_ the entire number them performance is out the window anyway.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch6.html#x13-1350006.4), this question is implementation specific:

> The finite-precision integer type `Int` covers at least the range [-2^29, 2^29-1]. As `Int` is an instance of the `Bounded` class, `maxBound` and `minBound` can be used to determine the exact `Int` range defined by an implementation.

I know of no implementations for which `maxBound :: Int` is larger than 2^63-1.